# Updating the Structure of Employee for List to Map in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++, couchbase-java-api

I have one class which was having data member as List.  
Due to requirement changes now I have updated the Structure of the class from

```
List<String> to Map<String, List<String>
```

Earlier structure of class was

```
Class Document{
 
List<String> doc;
}
```

Now Class is like

```
Class Documents{

Map<String,List<String>> doc;
}
```

I have Created a CouchBase query to update the existing record with the latest class structure.

My Query

```
update <bucketName> p
SET p.document.doc.["temp"] = p.document.doc
where p.applicationId = "13";
```

Comment: Couchbase is completely unrelated to couchdb. Why the couchdb tag?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the question/problem is